# Keeping file name when uploading to S3 with django-s3upload

Tags: jquery, python, django, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm using [django-s3upload](https://github.com/yaniv-aknin/django-s3upload) to upload files to my s3 bucket. I've got it up and running fine but it, for some reason I don't understand, renames all uploaded files to a random hex string with a .bin extension. I can see where in code this happening:

```
def get_upload_params(request):
    def make_policy():
        policy_object = {
            "expiration": (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'),
            "conditions": [
                { "bucket": settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME },
                { "acl": "public-read" },
                ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
                { "success_action_status": "201" }
            ]
        }
        return b64encode(dumps(policy_object).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', ''))

    def sign_policy(policy):
        return b64encode(hmac.new(settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, sha).digest())

    policy = make_policy()
    return HttpResponse(dumps({
        "policy": policy,
        "signature": sign_policy(policy),
        "key": "uploads/" + uuid4().hex + ".bin",
        "success_action_redirect": "/"
    }), content_type="application/json")
```

I can't figure out how to keep the file name intact. The jQuery file which does all the upload work client side is [here](https://github.com/yaniv-aknin/django-s3upload/blob/master/s3upload/static/jquery.fileupload.js).

Comment: django-s3upload is just a demo, it says. you will need to change its code to use different S3 keys.

Comment: I'm using it with different S3 keys and can get it uploading to my bucket fine, I just don't want it renaming filenames automatically